# finding an element in DOM which is just before the clicked element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I need to do something like this:

```
<ul><li>something</li></ul>
<div class='elm'>click me</div>     <!-- no 1  -->
<ul><li>something</li></ul>
<div class='elm'>click me</div>     <!-- no 2  -->
<ul><li>something</li></ul>
<div class='elm'>click me</div>     <!-- no 3  -->
<ul><li>something</li></ul>
<div class='elm'>click me</div>     <!-- no 4  -->
<ul><li>something</li></ul>
<div class='elm'>click me</div>     <!-- no 5  -->
```

then using jquery

```
$(".elm").click(function(){
   //some selector which returns the ul element which is just before this div element.
});
```

I need to select the ul element which is just before the div element which is clicked.

like if user clicks on div (# 4) then it should return the ul element which is just before the div (#4).

Comment: oh yes, it was because of copy/paste, now I have edited :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("div.elm").click(function() {
    // Get the previous element IF it's a UL (nothing otherwise)
    var previous = $(this).prev("ul");
});
```

See [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) in the docs.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eleri3)

If you wanted to *scan* back to the nearest previous sibling `ul`, skipping any elements in-between that aren't `ul`s, you'd do:

```
$("div.elm").click(function() {
    // Find a previous UL sibling, if any
    var previous = $(this).prevAll("ul:first");
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eleri3/2)

Answer (score 1):

If you give your elements a class instead of an ID to make it work, then you can use [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$(".elm").click(function(){
   var prev = $(this).prev();
});
```

**Note:** *IDs have to be unique*. If you assign the same ID to more than one element, most operations are only performed on the first element with this ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have a huge error there (use a validator if you dont belive me :)) )... you have more than one div with the same id add a counter to them or something. Also if you add a counter you can select it without problem.

function select(id)

{

var x = document.getElementById('elm'+id);

}

Anyway... if you want to do it without a counter use something like onclick="select(this.index)"

Comment: That's a comment, not an *answer*.  (A good comment, mind you, as of the question in its original form, but that's what the "comment" link is for.)